# How to get the probabilities of each class for the test instances in weka

Tags: classification, weka, data-mining

I have my training data with a binary column at the end, I need to run a classifier that gives me a numerical probability that it's correct. I've tried running it with the linear regression classifier and I get some minus numbers in the prediction column. I also tried it with the lazy iBk classifier but only got predictions (of 1) where the binary column was 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, not all algorithms provide that information.  Naive Bayes is a standard for that sort of thing and works surprising well under many conditions.

I had great results with RandomCommittee where probabilities were a key factor in our application.  Not only did we have to pick the top of the list, but we needed to know if there were any close runners-up.  When this happened the application paused and asked the user for clarification (which was stored back in the database, of course.)  RandomCommittee was chosen after extensive testing over time.

Comment: Naive Bayes is grey'd out as i'm using numerical values, i've used simple linear regression as that's one of the only ones available, will this still work?

Comment: You mentioned, "binary column".  Can you try "True", "False" instead of 1, 0?

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve and whether you are using the Weka GUI or Java API?